# Mouse position in xaml - wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, mouse, command

Is it possible to specify the position of the mouse as the value of the Parameter property of a Command in XAML. Something like the following:

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Create Link"
                      Command="{Binding CreateLink}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Mouse.Position}" >
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF, there is no Mouse.Position.  If you look at the [Mouse class members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse_members(v=VS.90).aspx), the closest thing is [Mouse.GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition(v=VS.90).aspx), which returns the position relative to some UI element.

I would recommend using the UI element itself as the Command Parameter, and having your Command call `Mouse.GetPosition` to retrieve positioning, if this is required in your DataContext for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, if you were looking to do it programatically, you can use the PointToScreen() as well as the Mouse.GetPosition(this) to get the absolute mouse point. Take a look at this should you need to do this programatically, not in XAML,

http://ivolo.mit.edu/post/WPF-Mouse-and-Point-Acrobatics.aspx